# Linking an Access database to VB.Net, starts at the fourth entry

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013, basic

I've linked a Microsoft Access 2007-2013 database to a form, however if there are more than three entries on the database, it always starts on the fourth one. If there are 3 entries, it begins on the first and works just fine.

This is the code for loading the database:

```
Sub LoadDataBase()
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection

    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim sql As String

    con.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0;Data Source = \\FILE\UserFolders$\Students\howea15\Desktop\FlashCardDB.accdb"

    con.Open()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM Flashcards"
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)

    da.Fill(ds, "Flashcards")
    con.Close()

    TotalRows = ds.Tables("Flashcards").Rows.Count
End Sub
```

I'm using VB 2010, .NET 4.6 if that helps.

Comment: Look at ordering the records in your `SELECT` statement. `SELECT * FROM Flashcards ORDER BY [ColumnName]`

Comment: You'd need an 'order by' statement if you wanted the results to be predictable.

Comment: @Jinx88909 Thanks, that worked! I'm still pretty new to the whole thing, especially SQL :)